# How Do I Correct mysql.rb Drivers?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems

For the last several days, I've been struggling to get ruby on rails to work on my mac. The main culprit is MySQL. Every time I fix one thing, another error shows up. I upgraded/downgraded MySQL to play nice with ruby, rail and gems, but nothing. My latest error is:

```
!!! The bundled mysql.rb driver has been removed from Rails 2.2. Please install the mysql gem and try again: gem install mysql.
```

/!\ FAILSAFE /!\  Wed Aug 05 21:09:23 -0700 2009
  Status: 500 Internal Server Error
  dlopen(/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/i686-darwin9.7.0/mysql.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.16.dylib...

I don't have libmysqlclient.16.dylib; just *.15.dylib. Tried all the techniques, even installed or tried to install ruby-mysql-0.2.6 posted at tmtm.org

FYI: Last error prior to the one stated above had to do with authentication.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this question is a bit old already, but since I got here after getting the same error (but on LINUX), I would like to post my solution for future reference.
I simply had to install **ruby-mysql.i686**

```
yum install ruby-mysql.i686
```

Hope it helps somebody else in the future... tnx

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed Xcode Developer tools? You can download it for free at http://developer.apple.com/.

Whenever I have issues with Ruby and MySQL, I never had Xcode installed. Could be wrong.

Comment: Yes. Everything is in place, or at least they should be. Every single error I get, has to with mysql. I know rails is working, because when I run "rails test_directory", it creates all the proper files and directories, and so on. Thanks for your input.

Comment: You don't need MySQL for the rails command to work, but good job solving your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

I don't know why and I don't know how, but took @Garrett's advice and re-installed Xcode. That didn't do anything. Went ahead and upgraded MySQL after that, which I had done before, and voilá! it worked. I'm guessing both re-installations finally got it working somehow. Weird!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below command . Provide the location of the mysql directory in your Mac .

sudo gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-dir= /usr/local/mysql

It looks like you haven't specified the location of mysql  directory .

Good luck !